# How can I run a service the would have access to my database and could run operations on it, but won't stuff up the UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service, architecture, android-architecture-components

I am building an app the needs to go through a collection of photos stored locally, which I import to a room database, and try to detect for each if it contains faces or not.
I've got everything sorted, my only issue is  how to run this operation, which could take a while, in a service that wouldn't stuff up the UI thread.

At first I wanted to use a `JobIntentService` but couldn't because I was unable to observeForever on a background thread, and couldn't use a simple observer because I have no lifecycleOwner to give to the `Observer`.

I've ended up using just a service, as soon as the operation starts my UI is pretty much stuck and if I try to do anything the app crashes.

I tried maybe `IntentService` but I can't use the observer in `onHandleIntent` because it's a worker thread and it doesn't let me, and when I run the operations under `onStartCommand` then it's just the same thing.

I feel like I am stuck with the architecture of this thing, I'd appreciate any ideas. Thank you.

This is my service:

```
class DetectJobIntentService : Service() {

    private val TAG = "DetectJobIntentServi22"
    lateinit var repo: PhotoRepository
    lateinit var observer : Observer<MutableList<Photo>>

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        val options = FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.Builder()
            .setClassificationMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ACCURATE)
            .setClassificationMode(FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .setMinFaceSize(0.15f)
            .build()

        val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
            .getVisionFaceDetector(options)

        repo = PhotoRepository(application)

        observer = Observer {
            for (file in it) {
                val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(application, Uri.parse(file.uri))
                AsyncTask.execute {
                    detector.detectInImage(image).addOnSuccessListener { list ->
                        if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
                            file.hasFaces = 1
                            repo.update(file)
                        } else {
                            file.hasFaces = 2
                            repo.update(file)
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        }

        repo.getAllPhotos().observeForever(observer)

        val notificationIntent= Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0)

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(tech.levanter.anyvision.R.string.channel_id))
            .setContentTitle("Detecting faces..")
            .setContentText("64 photos detected")
            .setSmallIcon(tech.levanter.anyvision.R.drawable.ic_face)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        startForeground(1, notification)

        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        repo.getAllPhotos().removeObserver(observer)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your code is in Kotlin, I'll advice you try out [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html). This would enable you dispatch expensive operations i.e. querying databases, making network requests/calls off to other threads thereby not blocking the `UIThread`. `Coroutines` help you avoid the hassle of `callbacks`. Also, Google just deprecated the `AsyncTask` API in favour of `Coroutines` as the way to go for multi-threading purposes.